# Was Super Mario Bros. 2 for the FDS a two-sided disk?

Tags: nes, super-mario-bros-the-lost-levels

I recently bought a Famicom Disk System, and am looking at buying some disks to go along with it. In particular, Mario Bros 1 and 2 (AKA "The Lost Levels").

In one eBay auction I'm looking at, an SMB2 disk the game on one side, and Volleyball on the other. Yet in [this Japanese ad](https://youtu.be/fWax6C3KPNU?t=25), the disk shown at the end has "A" printed on it, which makes me think it's two-sided.

To confuse things further, people in [this forum thread](https://themushroomkingdom.net/board/index.php?topic=14868.0) speak of the game being both one and two sided (with the one-sided disk having SMB1 on the other side).

So my questions are:

1. Was SMB2 a two-sided game?
2. If there was a two-sided version, are there any differences between that one and the one-sided version I'm looking at on eBay)?

Comment: Do you have pictures of the eBay one you are looking at?

Comment: @TimmyJim Here's the listing: http://web.archive.org/web/20191015195432/https://www.ebay.com/itm/Super-Mario-Bros-2-volley-ball-Famicom-NES-Disk-System-Used-From-Japan-16102/264476282729 and here's the images from the listing in case the images don't load: https://imgur.com/a/tMzjSXn

Answer (score 1):

Searching around yielded little to no results to answer your questions.  However, after you provided the images of the posting, I was able to translate [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq9tU.jpg) using Google's Image translator app on my phone:

[image]

Although it's not perfect, every time it seemed to come to the conclusion that the bottom bullet basically says "No software on Side B, new software can be written."

[image: No Side B]

Due to what little is available about this, I would believe that this game is only one-sided.

<sub>Side note: I got some interesting translations, like the red text in the above image saying "Fur Peeler" - I think the red text says "Family Computer Disk System" but the plastic on the game case blurs it somewhat in the image</sub>

**Edit:**

The eBay listing stated that it contains "Super Mario Bros 2 + Volley Ball", so this particular disk seems to have two sides, but for two different games.

[image: eBay Image]

Comment: Ah yes, I have fond memories of Fur peeler, and also playing EL ball :). I ended up going for a Mario 1 & 2 disk which was slightly cheaper overall. If it turns out that there is a two-sided version, I'll try and pick it up.

Comment: @Grayda I was really curious to see what the "B" section in the middle would translate to. But everytime is seemed to be either "El Ball" or the word "Labor". It kept detecting the beginning piece of the first Japanese character as a "/" as well. I thought it would be some sort of dash-limited word since the original picture looks like a few characters with dashes in between.

Comment: Heh, the "El Ball" should be バレーボール which is Volleyball in katakana (Barēbōru).

Comment: The red text is ディスクカード, "Disk Card" (Disukukādo).

Comment: @Showsni I wonder if [Volleyball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volleyball_(video_game)) was written to side B at some later date as Super Mario Bros 2 was released before Volleyball.  Considering the paper says Side B has no software, I wonder if Side B was later written to.  It's hard to tell from the original image, but it sort of looks like the B section of the packaging is a sticker that is covering what I assume was a blank box.  It's certainly whiter in color than Section A

Comment: @Grayda Oh - looks like the original eBay listing actually says that Volleyball is included.  Taking Showsni's comment into consideration, this makes sense!

Comment: @TimmyJim Certainly possible; you can see from http://www.oldiesrising.com/images_lesaviezvous/takeru/disk%20writer2.jpg that both Volleyball and Mario 2 are options for the Famicom Disk Writer. Apparently the shopkeeper who operated it would put the stickers for the game onto the disk for you after it had written.